# How to get a session value in cshtml file in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-session

Pls help me out, the value is storing in the session for the particular user ,When i am retrieving the session value from cshtml, It is showing the PC-username instead of the particular username present in the data base. please suggest session code to show the particular user name.   I am using this code in Cotrtoller.

```
{public ActionResult LogIn(Models.Tbl_Users user)
        {
            Session["Username"] = user.UserName;
            var sessionval = Session["Username"].ToString();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Isvalid(user.UserName, user.UserPassword))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);

                    string status = Session["Username"].ToString();
                    if (status == "admin")
                    {
                        //  return RedirectToAction("adminpage", "UserLogIn");
                        return RedirectToAction("adminpage", "UserLogin");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("userpage", "UserLogIn");
 }                   }
```

this is my cshtml code:

```
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        { 

        <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>

                @Html.ActionLink("Log Out","LogOut","UserLogIn")



        }
```

}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you could access the session variable directly using

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"].ToString();
```

Comment: Its working,Thank you very much,,,But the session user name is displaying like as Label,,,How to make it as hyper link,,,pls help

Comment: try this `@Html.ActionLink(@HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"].ToString(), "NameOfHandlingFunction");`

Comment: How would you do that if the session is an object?